# How to control when image data is loaded into memory in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: image, windows-8, io, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

When creating an image in a Windows Store App, how do you control when data is read from disk?

In WPF, you could control when an image was read from disk using [BitmapCacheOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx). `BitmapCacheOptions.OnDemand` would postpone reading data from disk until the image data was actually needed. There were a few downsides to this:

- IO costs often appeared as UI delays;
- if a stream was used as the image source, then the stream could not be closed;
- if a file was used as the image source, then the file was locked.

To address that problem you could use `BitmapCacheOptions.OnLoad` to read the image into memory immediately.

How do you control when image data is loaded into memory in Windows Store Apps?

WPF code would look something like this:

```cs
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapImage.UriSource = path;
bitmapImage.EndInit();
bitmapImage.Freeze();
```

**Edit** - More info

WPA shows that getting an 8.8mb image onto the screen costs ~330ms. Of that, 170ms is spent on file IO (including 37ms for antivirus to check the file), and 160ms is spent on WIC decoding.

Any ideas how to control when the file IO happens or how to trigger WIC decoding?
[image: Right click and open in new tab to see full size]
(Right click and open in new tab to see full size)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please, share your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Store Apps I suggest looking into the AccessCache APIs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.aspx

Specifically the [StorageApplicationPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.aspx) class. With it you can add various storage items to be accessed.

Take a look at the [FilePickerSampl](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba)e (or [FileAccessSample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597)) app for more information on how it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this, but it's not what I'm looking for. The API's you mention give you access to files, but I'm interested in the next part: once I have access how do I control when the image is decoded into memory... and how do you control which thread does the decode?